# Complex linear system help?

Tags: linear-algebra

Having been away for the lesson this was done in, I have no clue how to do this homework question, and there is nothing in the notes about it. The question is to solve this linear system:
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
6 & -13\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}\right]=(3+2i)\left[\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y
\end{array}\right]$$

How would I start this question?

Thanks.

Comment: take a look here for formatting http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}6 & -13\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \end{bmatrix} = (3 + 2i)\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$

This looks like $(3 + 2i)$ is an eigenvalue for the matrix!

Subtract both sides:

$\begin{bmatrix}6 - (3 + 2i) & -13\\1 & 0 - (3 + 2i)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3 - 2i & -13\\1 & -3 - 2i\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to solve linear systems, there's two points that I can see might be bothering you. One is that this involves a complex number - this changes nothing, just proceed as you would with real numbers. The other is that there are variables on both sides of the system. This is not a problem, just move them all to the same side.

Perform the matrix/vector multiplication on the right to get a vector. Now you have an equality between two vectors. Write down the system of equations obtained by equating each one of their coordinates, and you should obtain something like this:

$$6x-13y=(3+2i)x$$
$$x=(3+2i)y$$
Then solve the system with whatever method you prefer.